# Checking for Expiration before 3 months, 1 month and date of expiration in Textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, datetime

I want to check or remind the expiration date before 3 months (yellow), 1 month (orange) and a date expiration (red) in my text box.
This is my code but i have only a date of expired in my conditions.

```
<?php
$today = date('m/d/Y');
$expired = '10/22/2020'; //example
if (strtotime($today) >= strtotime($expired)) {
?>
   Date: <input type="text" name="expired" id="expired" value = "<?php echo $expired; ?>" style="background-color:#F06D6A;"/>      
<?php    
}else {
?>
   Date: <input type="text" name="expired" id="expired" value = "<?php echo $expired; ?>" style="background-color:#FFF;"/>
<?php    
}
?>
```

Comment: Careful! `strtotime()` will interpret 12/10/2020 as "10 December 2020", where you expect it to be "12 October 2020"!

Comment: how i will solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to handle things. See comments for a step-by-step explanation.

```
<?php

// Careful! strtotime() will interpret 12/10/2020 as "10 December 2020", where you expect it to be 12 October 2020!
// Consider the code below for an alternative, more robust solution.

$today = new DateTime;

// Added time for uniformity.
// "Notice of default" used to indicate the final date for possible payment,
// before services are suspended and/or legal action is taken.
// use setDate() and setTime() to explicitly set the date/time, to avoid caveats with international date formats
// as pointed out above.
$noticeOfDefaultAt = (new DateTime)->setDate(2021, 2, 10)->setTime(7, 0);

// First reminder (yellow) sent 3 months before expiration date.
// DateInterval() accepts a formatted string which decodes here to:
// P = Period of
// 3 = 3
// M = Months
// Use sub() to get the period offset from the final payment date ($noticeOfDefault)
$firstReminderAt = (clone $noticeOfDefaultAt)->sub(new DateInterval('P3M'));
// Second reminder (orange) sent 1 month before expiration date.
$secondReminderAt = (clone $noticeOfDefaultAt)->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));

// Default to transparent if within payment period.
$bgColor = 'transparent';

if ($today >= $firstReminderAt && $today < $secondReminderAt)
    // Today is within grace period of first reminder.
    $bgColor = 'yellow';

if ($today >= $secondReminderAt && $today < $noticeOfDefaultAt)
    // Today is within grace period of second reminder.
    $bgColor = 'orange';
    
if ($today >= $noticeOfDefaultAt)
    // We have a really sh*tty customer. Send legal team.
    $bgColor = 'red';

// Change the color names to any rgb-hex value you want and use them in your "style" attribute.
echo $bgColor;
```

Comment: my date format is m/d/Y like 10/22/2020. how i convert it like this setDate(2021, 2, 10)?

Comment: If you don't have the integers for those date components, you can get them like this: `[$month, $day, $year] = explode('/', $yourDateString);` and then pass them as such: `setDate($year, $month, $day)`. You can optionally cast them to ints before you do so (`(int)$year` or `+$year`).